# How to request a window be activated with the Wayland Protocol

Tags: wayland

Using [xdg-activation-v1](https://wayland.app/protocols/xdg-activation-v1) it's possible to activate a window although the mechanism to do so seems to assume the window being activated is from another application.

This seems useful when one application wants to activate another's window however it's quite involved in the case an application wants to activate one of it's own windows (where creating a token, making the request & responding to the request is quite involved).

Is there a way for an application to request activation of a window which it controls? (where the `wl_surface` for example is already known).

On X11 for example `_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW` can be used for an application to request the window be active.

Answer (score 0):

xdg-activation-v1 can be used to activate a window, it's not as complicated as the API might make it seem.

While you do need to create a token and listen for the token within the same application, there is no need to create a unique token ID as you can compare the activation tokens pointer.

This can be done as follows:

- Each window stores an `xdg_activation_token` (defaulting to NULL).
- Upon activation assign an activation token: `xdg_activation_v1_get_activation_token` (clearing the existing token when non-null).
- Setup data for the activation token:

  - `xdg_activation_token_v1_set_app_id(..)` (of the currently running application).
  - `xdg_activation_token_v1_set_serial(..)` (for the the input events that trigger activation).
  - `xdg_activation_token_v1_set_surface(..)` (for the window **requesting** activation).

  Note that some of this information might not be available (the serial or surface for e.g.). Activation may still work depending on the wayland-compositor, although it is free to ignore the activation request, and insufficient information makes this more likely.
- Set a listener using the `xdg_activation_token_v1_listener` struct.

  All the listener needs to do is:

  - Check the call-backs `xdg_activation_token_v1` argument matches the token stored in the window (cast from the first data argument).
  - Call `xdg_activation_v1_activate(..)` forwarding the `token` argument passed to the callback.
  - The token should then be destroyed using `xdg_activation_token_v1_destroy`.
- Commit the newly created token via `xdg_activation_token_v1_commit(..)`

---

- SDL was used as a reference for these steps, see the `Wayland_RaiseWindow` function.
- An example of a [patch that implements this](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/commit/3071ec486bffd0fef180f221a85f0b15f07b7950).